# Overloaded method, invalid arguments C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay I'm trying to move from VB to C# with mixed success.

I'm getting the following errors:

1. The best overloaded method match for
   '_DataInteraction.stdReturnDataTable(string, ref
   System.Collections.Generic.List,
   string)' has some invalid arguments
2. Argument 2 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword

Both referencing: the myParamList noted with ****** in

I have this code in C#

```
{

    List<SqlParameter> myParamList = new List<SqlParameter>();
    SqlParameter myParam = default(SqlParameter);

    myParam = new SqlParameter("@sAMAccountName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    myParam.Value = ID;
    myParamList.Add(myParam);

    **dt = _DI.stdReturnDataTable("cit_ResolveUser", myParamList, "x");**

    return dt;
}
```

Now the code for stdReturnDataTable (just the top part which accepts the arguments)

```
public static DataSet stdReturnDataset(string procedureName, ref List<SqlParameter> myParameters, string db)
    {
       //code
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, you should pass the argument with the `ref` keyword:

```
dt = DataInteraction.stdReturnDataTable("cit_ResolveUser", ref myParamList, "ParabisIntranet");
```

Also, as per your comment, it's a static method, you can not call it through an instance variable. Instead you need to qualify it using the typename.

But I suspect the ref keyword is actually not needed here, you can probably just remove it from the method signature.

```
public static DataSet stdReturnDataset(string procedureName, 
                                       List<SqlParameter> myParameters, 
                                       string db)
```

Comment: It's a static method, so you need to access it via the type name rather than an instance.  what type is _DI? You need to do SomeClass.stdReturnDataset() where SomeClass is whatever type houses the stdReturnDataset method.

Comment: So qualify it with the type name instead of an instance reference.

Comment: It's a static method, so you should call it using `ClassName.MethodName` syntax, exactly as the error message says. What's the name of the class containing the `stdReturnDataset` method?

Comment: Thank you @DylanSmith _DI was just a new instance of DataInteraction class which housed the stdReturnDataset() function

Comment: Can anyone explain why _DataInteraction _DI = new _DataInteraction(); and using _DI would not work?

Comment: @Ryan Because the method is marked [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx), i.e. it doesn't "belong" to a specific instance but to the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `ref` keyword with your method call.

```
dt = _DI.stdReturnDataTable("cit_ResolveUser", ref myParamList, "ParabisIntranet");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the ref keywoard:

dt = _DI.stdReturnDataTable("cit_ResolveUser", **ref** myParamList, "ParabisIntranet");